# DHCP server on HPE MSR2004 24G not working

Tags: router, dhcp, hp

I set up a new MSR2004 router and can't seem to get DHCP to work. Here are the corresponding config lines:

```
 dhcp enable

 vlan 12
  name Guest Wifi VLAN

 dhcp server ip-pool guest-wifi
  gateway-list 192.168.210.1
  address range 192.168.210.10 192.168.210.240
  dns-list 192.168.210.1
  expired day 0 hour 8

 interface Vlan-interface12
  ip address 192.168.210.1 255.255.255.0
  dhcp server apply ip-pool guest-wifi

 interface GigabitEthernet0/26
  port link-mode bridge
  port access vlan 12
```

The client connected to port 0/26 is not able to obtain an IP address.

Update: The router is reachable using a static ip. So it's really about the dhcp server.

Comment: If you configure the client connected to port 0/26 with a static IP address in the subnet 192.168.210.0/24, is the client able to ping the default gateway 192.168.210.1? With this test you can see if there is a layer 2 connectivity issue (if the client can not ping the default gateway when having static IP address) or there is something missing for the DHCP configuration (if the client can ping the default gatway when having static IP address but can not get IP address via DHCP)

Comment: Yes, that is working. It's just the dynamic address assignment that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, even though the pool can be bound to an interface, you have to specify the network within the pool:

```
dhcp server ip-pool internal
 gateway-list 192.168.200.1
 network 192.168.200.0 mask 255.255.254.0
 address range 192.168.200.10 192.168.201.200
 dns-list 192.168.200.1
 expired day 0 hour 8
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: I would love nothing more than that. However, I have to wait 24 hours to do so. Will do asap.